# How do I target a child of a specific class?

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to target only the top level list items that are direct children from the `ol` with the class foo. I want to make them red.

```css
ol.foo>li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ol class='foo'>
    <li>section 1</li>
    <li>section 2
      <ol>
        <li>step 1</li>
        <li>step 2</li>
        <li>step 3</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>section 3</li>
    <li>section 4</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I'm wanting to only effect the list items (section 1, section 2, section 3 and section 4) I don't want to change, item 1, item 2, step 1, step 2 or step 3

Answer (score 3):

The color for your first li is getting inherited to other list items.

The other answers here are using the color black to fix this.

Here is a solution that allows you to get the desired affect without having to define another color.

```css
ol.foo li {
  color: initial;
}

ol.foo > li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ol class='foo'>
    <li>section 1</li>
    <li>section 2
      <ol>
        <li>step 1</li>
        <li>step 2</li>
        <li>step 3</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>section 3</li>
    <li>section 4</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it

```css
ol.foo>li {
  color: red;
}

ol.foo>li>ol{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ol class='foo'>
    <li>section 1</li>
    <li>section 2
      <ol>
        <li>step 1</li>
        <li>step 2</li>
        <li>step 3</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>section 3</li>
    <li>section 4</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to add a second selector to change it back because there isn't a preexisting rule dictating the color:

```
ol.foo>li {
  color: red;
}
ol.foo > li ol li {
  color: black;
}
```